# Does the intercom supports new GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, intercom

The way of working with GCM was updated since march 2015, so does the intercom.io supports new realization? Because here (https://docs.intercom.io/Install-on-your-mobile-product/using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-with-intercom-for-android) is old documentation and I didn't find anything up-to-date

Answer (score 1):

We have recently updated our GCM docs to match the updates from GCM 3.0.
It's the very same link as you listed above. Check it out and let me know if you have any feedback on it. I'll check back in here but feel free to contact us on [www.intercom.io](http://www.intercom.io)